# apache pulsar Transaction pending ack generate managedLedgerStats fail! issue

Tags: apache-pulsar

apache pulsar  Transaction pending ack generate managedLedgerStats fail! issue

05:48:00.084 [prometheus-stats-43-1] WARN  org.apache.pulsar.broker.stats.prometheus.TransactionAggregator - Transaction pending ack generate managedLedgerStats fail!
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.BrokerServiceException$NotAllowedException: Pending ack handle don't use managedLedger!

I checked the pulsar services like broker,bookeeper and zookeeper